# Geometrically speaking, what "is" linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry

I have always thought of linear algebra (LA) as a *system for solving linear equations*. However, revisiting it after about 7-10 years, I realize that such a *definition* is more appropriate for "matrices" but not LA as a whole.

Although we do solve a system of linear equations to answer some questions in LA, I personally am not satisfied with that interpretation. There are a lot of (linear) *transformations* happening under the hood. It seems, that the *definition* of LA can be *broadened* to say that it's *geometry by the way of linear transformations*. That is, we "solve" for *things* within the system by *transforming space and its containing "objects"* (i.e., translate, shear, scale, rotate) vs. keeping *space* fixed like in a purely Cartesian setting.

Is this correct? What would be a more mathematically albeit layman friendly way to characterize this kind of *geometry*? It seems, everything that can be done in Euclidean Geometry can also be done in a Vector space and it's entirely possible that when in vector space if we are to find a good orthonomal basis (e.g., Eigens) we may get a much simpler representation of the problem. However, this simplification comes as a result of *transforming space* and seeing how the *geometrical objects* change along with it. Is this correct?

Would it be fair to say that (geometrically speaking) LA is a dual view of Euclidean Geometry (EG)? If so, then is there something that can be done in LA that cannot be done in EG? How could one combine  the *definition* of LA and its relation to EG?

I could be totally wrong and hence the question to help me understand what may I be missing. I may be groping in the dark and would appreciate if I could be pointed in the right direction. None of the books (Strang, LA done right...), web/blogs, articles, history etc., that I was are able to "define" LA AFAIK.

Comment: This question might be a good one for the [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com), as the folks there may be able to speak to the original motivations for the term in particular and the field in general.

Comment: A very broad definition of Linear Algebra could be "The study of numbers arranged in rows and columns". After that, it tends to break down in sub genres.

Comment: For me, linear algebra is the study of modules over rings. We usually begin with the ring being a field. The fact that finite coproducts agree with finite products tells us that we can fruitfully use matrices to represent linear maps. When we're over a field, studying endomorphisms leads to studying canonical forms. Then the fun begins when we relax back to working over a general ring